# VBA to move email folders & contents

Tags: vba, outlook

I am stumped to work on a script to move an email folder (& contents) to a different parent folder. This folder is no under parent Inbox.  I have a basic, self-taught understanding of VBA. 
eg. ThisOutlookSession/[FolderA] to move to ThisOutlookSession/Inbox/[FolderA]

Ive found lots of examples to move emails but not folders.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Edit:

```
Private Sub ImportFolder() <br>
'''''''''
'' Assume for this example so im not overloading code that I have already    created the CSV that im drawing data from, opened in excel & this Macro is running from Outlook
'''''''''

Dim xlWkb As Object ' As Workbook
Dim xlSht As Object ' As Worksheet
Set xlSht = xlWkb.Worksheets(1) 'set active being first worksheet
Dim iRow As Integer
Dim ChilCol As Integer
Dim parentFolderName
iRow = 1 'set start a Row1
ChilCol = 1 'set start as ColA

'Set Parent as Static nomination in head macros

While xlSht.Cells(iRow, 1) <> "" 'while Parent is not blank

If ChilCol <= 1 Then
Set objParentFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Else
parentFolderName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, ChilCol - 1) 'set the parent to be the previous Column

Set objParentFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(parentFolderName)
End If

'Set name for the new folder
  newFolderName = xlSht.Cells(iRow, ChilCol) 

On Error Resume Next

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Dim objNewFolder As Outlook.Folder

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
If newFolderName = "Inbox" Then
 newFolderName = Nothing
 End If

 'If ParentFolder = newFolderName
   '

Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders(newFolderName)

 '' This is where I am unsure - I have a Archive email folder on same hierarchy as Inbox 
 '' due to how mobile Outlook displays folders. This part of the code should check that if 
 '' the Parent Folder for the new folder to be mapped in then move the Folder in Archive to Inbox\SubFolder

        If objNewFolder.Parent = "zArchive" And objNewFolder.Parent = parentFolderName Then
            objNewFolder.MoveTo Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
        End If

'If no issues, then create the Folder
If objNewFolder Is Nothing Then 'if no value
    Set objNewFolder = objParentFolder.Folders.Add(newFolderName) 'add folder
End If       

 ' make new folder the parent
Set objParentFolder = objNewFolder
     If xlSht.Cells(iRow, ChilCol) = "" Then  ''unless blank
        iRow = iRow + 1 'new row
        ChilCol = 0 'reset ChildColumn
    End If
    ChilCol = ChilCol + 1 ' move to next nesting column
  Set objNewFolder = Nothing 'required to reset the New Folder name
Wend

xlWkb.Close
xlApp.Quit
Set xlWkb = Nothing
Set xlApp = Nothing
Set objParentFolder = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Here is a post that will help you in writing good questions; ones that won't be closed and might even get answered: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Folder.MoveTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/outlook-vba/articles/folder-moveto-method-outlook?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaol11.chm1998)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv15)%26rd%3Dtrue) method which moves a folder to the specified destination folder.

```
Sub MoveFolder() 
  Dim myNameSpace As Outlook.NameSpace 
  Dim myFolder As Outlook.Folder 
  Dim myNewFolder As Outlook.Folder 

  Set myNameSpace = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
  Set myFolder = myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts) 
  Set myNewFolder = myFolder.Folders.Add("My Test Contacts") 
  myNewFolder.MoveTo myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox) 
End Sub
```

You may find the [Getting Started with VBA in Outlook 2010](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee814736(v=office.14).aspx) article helpful.

Comment: Many thanks. Ill give this a try.
I gather that the key in this sample is myNewFolder.MoveTo myNameSpace.GetDeafultFolder(olFolderInbox).
Im just wondering why you have olFolderContacts included?

.. so if I have the myNewFolder already set (reading from a csv) then my added code above should work?